# Cast a Java Object to Integer

Tags: java, swing, object, integer, int

Error shown from the below code is: Cannot Cast an object to integer. I don't know what else will i include to cast it.

```
private RowFilter filter(final int itemsPerPage,final int target) {
        return new RowFilter() {
            public boolean include(Entry entry) {

                /* HERE I AM RECEIVING ERROR: Multiple markers at this line
                - Type mismatch: cannot convert from  Object to int
                - Cannot cast from Object to int */
                int ei = (int) entry.getIdentifier();

                return (target * itemsPerPage <= ei && ei < target
                        * itemsPerPage + itemsPerPage);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: It will be an `Integer` (object) rather than `int` (primitive).  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Can you put Entry's getidentifier method signature?

Comment: @AndrewThompson If it's an Integer object, shouldn't this code still work, since it'll be unboxed automatically?

Comment: Too true, all will work, but without [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), it's hard to say what the OP is doing wrong :-)

Comment: shouldn't the method return a generified RowFilter, something like RowFilter<MyDataType, Integer) filter, and a similarly generified implementation of include?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is:

```
int ei = ((Integer) entry.getIdentifier()).intValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

case cast exception need refactor as:
int ei = ((Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(entry.getIdentifier())).intValue());

Comment: wondering what you expect as type of identifier (except Integer in the case of Table/Row/Filter)?

Answer (score 0):

I think your method is returning `Integer` object here,if that is the case you need to do like this:

```
int ei =  ((Integer)entry.getIdentifier()).intValue();
```